# web3 only works with metamask but no mobile metamask or trustwallet etc

Tags: metamask

i stripped down to the bare minimum to interact with a contract with metamask
it works nice, i can call/transact nicely with only minimum of html/js

but on mobile metamask or trustwallet it simply does not do anything at all.

please see my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/540uayj6/

what did i miss? i tried putting web3.js manually in script tags, did not help.

thanks for any hints.

Comment: same here, if I comment out the Metamask part, it opens the TrustWallet popup (from the extension)